# Live preview aptana on different monitor

Tags: google-chrome, aptana

Is there any way to use the live preview ( [side-by-side preview](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Side-by-Side+Previewing) ) in an external window/external browser?

I want to be able to have the code on one monitor and the Live preview on another, but if I open the preview directly in Chrome, it doesn't auto-update, and if I use the side-by-side preview I can not open it in a different window.

Maybe there is some chrome extension to make the auto-updates done in Aptana's live preview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found a chrome extension to do the job, it's called [LivePage](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/livepage/pilnojpmdoofaelbinaeodfpjheijkbh?hl=en)

The good thing is that it isn't even related to aptana or another IDE, it simply checks for file changes and refreshes the page. :)

Comment: Have anything that isn't specific to chrome? Perhaps a firefox version?
I am searching for one myself as I post this.